# Why do I get "not_authed"-error from Slack when sending a post-request from c#?

Tags: c#, json, slack-api

I am trying to serialize an object into Json  and then send it to Slack. I have done this successfully without serializing but instead using "Dictionary" and "FormUrlEncodedContent" and then send it.
But now, for the purpose of making things easier and more agile, I just wanted to create one JSon-class which I could serialize and then use for every request I want to send.

Here is my code:

### My JsonObject:

```
    public class JsonObject
    {
        private string _token = "xoxp-MyToken";
        [JsonProperty("token")]
        public string token { get { return _token; } }
        [JsonProperty("channel")]
        public string channel { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("as_user")]
        public bool as_user = true;      
        [JsonProperty("username")]
        public string username { get;set; } 
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string text { get; set; }
}
```

### My client:

```
public class BpsHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient { };
    public Uri UriMethod { get; set; }

    public BpsHttpClient(string webhookUrl)
    {
        UriMethod = new Uri(webhookUrl);
    }        

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileAsync(StringContent requestContent)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, UriMethod);
        request.Content = requestContent;
        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        return response;
    }
}
```

### Main:

```
 class MainArea
    {
        public static void Main( string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(SendMessage());
            }
            catch(Exception ass)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ass);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        private static async Task SendMessage()
        {
            var client = new BpsHttpClient("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");
            JsonObject JO = new JsonObject();
            JO.channel = "DCW21NBHD";
            JO.text = "This is so much fun :D !";
            var Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JO, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

            var StringJson = new StringContent(Json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var DeSon = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json);

            Console.WriteLine(DeSon); //this is for me to see if my JsonObject looks correct - it does ;)
            Console.ReadKey();

            var Response = await client.UploadFileAsync(StringJson);

            string AnswerContent = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(AnswerContent);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

}

When I run the code I allways get the answer:

> Output: 
>   `{"ok":false,"error":"not_authed"}`

although I think my JsonObject looks right - it has the token in there... 
Anybody have an idea why?

Answer (score 1):

So, i figured it out - I SHALL NOT put my token in the JsonObject I want to send.

The solution in this case (using `httpclient`) is that one has to add a header for authorization to the client, like so:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "lé token");
```

and then it works.

Comment: Its actually not that obvious that Slack no longer accepts your token as normal parameter when you use JSON. Its actually an issue that I have seen many people posting about on SO. ;-) Besides, please no expletives. I removed it.